# Teradata SQL Assistant - CALL Failed HY000: User Defined Function source on the client is not supported by the driver

Tags: functions, teradata, r

Using Teradata SQL Assistant to install a user defined R script fails with an error.
The call looks like this:

```
SET SESSION SEARCHUIFDBPATH = demouser; -- Tells the linux user tduser, where to find the installed script
DATABASE demouser;                                      -- Sets the active database
CALL SYSUIF.INSTALL_FILE('test','test.R','cz!C:\\Temp\\sample2.R');     --installs the script with <script_name>, <script_filename>, and <script_local_location> to active database
```

The error message is

> CALL Failed. HY000: User Defined Function source on the client is not supported by the driver

I am using the current ODBC 64 bit Version from the ODBC Driver for Teradata - Suite 15.10.08.

Comment: My installation of UDF on Teradata had always been via the CLIv2 interface. Have you tried using BTEQ?

Comment: After switching to Teradata Studio it worked. Seems like an issue within the SQL Assistant

Comment: glad it worked out.